# Power BI - Unpivot a few columns in a table without interfere the remains columns

Tags: powerbi, unpivot

So I have this table:

**Original Table**

[image: 1]

I would like to transform the Defect columns into only one without affecting the total of the Inspected column. I've tried the Unpivot the selected columns and brought me this result

**Unpivot selected columns**

[image: 2]

The total of inspected changed from 13 to 52. To solve that problem I've tried to duplicate the table and unpivot only the defects and remaining the inspected in the other table, however I need to make calculations between those tables and both are already related to a third table. Someone has any idea how can I solve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is your final required output?

Comment: Are you asking for a "Total Defects" column, which is the sum of all "DefectX" columns?

Comment: I would like to have the sum of Inspected without change. Keep the same value. The defects part, the output is actually ok  by making the unpivot. Well I figured it out a not so elegant solution. I've created these two tables and unpivot only the defect then I divided the sum of defect values from one table by the sum of inspected in the other table and I'm using two filters from the particularities I need. Ex: the two tables created two columns of type products so I need to filter two times (one for each table) to get the correct relation of this calculation.

Comment: We need to understand your relation and the calculations you are making to be able to help you

Answer (score 0):

Add column by example after selecting Attributes, ie Attribute Index.
Calculate count nulls, errors and percentages against the Attribute column total

Calculated Value = SUMX(VALUES(Attribute Index),CALCULATE(MAX(Value)))